# can git manager files from different folds

Tags: git

I want to manager all my configuration files in one repo at Github.

for example, I have 3 folder: folderA, folderB, folderC

folderA has file: confA

folderB has file: confB

folderC has file: confC

at folder A

```
git init
git remote add origin repoURL
git add confA
git commit -m "adding confA"
git push -u origin master
```

now in repo at Github, there is configA

when I do the same to folderB

I get an error saying I have to clone repo to local first.

```sh
error: failed to push some refs to 'xxxxxx'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

That's the problem, 
I do not want to have a copy of repo in my folders, 
just push one file in folders to remote repo.

and the configuration folders are everywhere, there are also other files in it.

and repo for every conf file is also not a good option for me.

Comment: You can put these folders in one git repository.

Comment: as i mentioned above, the folders are everywhere. it is nearly impossible to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to manage multiple configuration files, but it isn't practical to have one large, overarching repository that covers all of the files.  An example of this might be if they all live in different places in `/etc`.

It is possible to do that with Git, but it requires a slightly different approach.  You can create a single repository in another location (say, in the place you normally store repositories) and place all of the configuration files as you like there.  You can then use a script or Makefile to install the modified versions to the proper location.  If it isn't possible to prevent them from being modified in their present location, you can have a script that copies them from that location into the repo, and then commit them as you like.

This is the approach many people take with their personal dotfiles, since they may not want to have their entire home directory be a Git repository.  They can then use a script to copy their files into the proper location in their home directory.

If you're looking for a solution that deals with more extensive configuration files across a wide variety of systems, you may prefer a configuration management system like Puppet.